# How to reset variable value in jquery after ajax completed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, variables

I have this script to disable ajax call button after ajax stop for 5 seconds to limit number of requests in minute.

It works fine for first ajax call but in second call have no countdown timer and not worked. it seems sec value set to 0 after first call.

Now, How to reset sec var to "5" after every ajax call?

```
var sec = 5;
var timer = document.getElementById("timer");
body = $("#domain");
$(document).on({
    ajaxStart: function() {
        $("#domain").addClass("loading haveresult"); 
        $("#checkthis").attr("disabled", true);
    },
    ajaxStop: function countDown() {
        $("#domain").removeClass("loading");
        timer.innerHTML = sec;
        if (sec <= 0) {
            $("#timer").fadeTo(2500, 0);
            timer.innerHTML = "";
            $("#checkthis").removeAttr("disabled");
            return;
        }
        sec -= 1;
        window.setTimeout(countDown, 1000);
    }
});
```

Comment: Just set the `sec = 5` before the `return` in your `if (sec <= 0)` block

Comment: Good Job. Thank You @Icepickle.